# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with string but not with char*

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I have a very weird and complicated bug related to the functioning of the string in C++.
I wrote MWE (minimal working example) that I compile with a online IDE ([code here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/VvtPbcQPa2)) :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BaseOption {
public:
    BaseOption& operator=(const BaseOption& option) {
        return *this;
    }
};

class DerivedOption: public BaseOption
{

public:
    string str = "foo";

    DerivedOption& operator=(const DerivedOption& option) {
        this->str = option.str;
        this->BaseOption::operator=(option);
        return *this;
    };
};

class BaseObject {
public:
    BaseObject(BaseOption* option) {
        this->option = option;
}
private:
    BaseOption* option;
};

class DerivedObject : public BaseObject {
public:
    DerivedObject(DerivedOption option)
    : BaseObject(this->OptionConstructor(option)){}
    DerivedOption option;
private:
    DerivedOption* OptionConstructor(DerivedOption& option){
        this->option = option;
        return &this->option;
    }
};


int main() {
    DerivedOption option;
    DerivedObject object(option);
    cout << "The program ran without error." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code return a Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) at runtime

**but** when I remplace

```cpp
string str = "foo";
```

by

```cpp
char* str = (char*)"foo";
```

the code works correctly.
Can someone explain that?

Comment: `BaseObject(this->OptionConstructor(option))` the `this` isn't constructed yet at that point.  Probably going to cause problems.  Make your constructor helper function `static`.

Comment: Code also works if you replace `string str = "foo";` with `string str = string("foo");` (at least, it does on MSVC). Could be a clue?

Comment: It's this line that crashes: `this->str = option.str;`

Comment: @Adrian On the online IDE use `string str = string("foo");` does not change anything.

Comment: @Adrian, Ok but why ? I want an explanation.

Comment: @MatthieuH So do I!  So far, I can only guess - explicit construction of a `string` *versus* initialization/assignment? It's certainly got me going.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica • it'll crash there... if you are lucky.  The string object has not been constructed yet at that point, so it's just uninitialized bits.  That problem stems from using `this` before it has been constructed.

Comment: The line `this->str = option.str;` calls copy-assignment operator of `std::string`, but `this->str` is not initialized yet. For example, It may crash because copy-assignment operator tries to deallocate memory pointed by `this->str`, but fails because `this->str` does not point to correct memory (it is not initialized and may contain garbage).

Comment: @purecuteness Excellent! I smelt UB but couldn't nail it down - you did that. Consider  posting an answer - you're guaranteed at least one upvote!

Comment: @purecuteness So did you say that my string is built after the constructor call? That doesn't make any sense !

Comment: Constructors of members are called after constructors of base classes. `OptionConstructor` is called before `BaseObject` constructor, hence it is called before `option` member constructor. Inside `OptionConstructor` you're trying to assign to `option` member, but it's not constructed - you can't work with it yet.

Comment: @purecuteness Ok I understood, my problem is at the end of `BaseObject` consturctor I call a an `isValid()` method and this methods fail if option is a `null_ptr`. My solution is to pass a default `BaseOption` in `baseObject` constructor and set the value of pointer inside contructor of `DerivedOption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solution my problem I did something like this:

```cpp
class BaseObject {
public:
    BaseObject(BaseOption* option) {
        option != nullptr ? this->option = option : this->option = new BaseOption();
    }
protected :
    BaseOption* option;
};

class DerivedObject : public BaseObject {
public:
    DerivedObject(DerivedOption option)
    : BaseObject(nullptr) {
        this->option = option;
        delete this->BaseObject::option;
        this->BaseObject::option;
    }
    DerivedOption option;

};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have very peculiar constructor of `DerivedObject`. Change it to something like this:

```
class DerivedObject : public BaseObject {
public:
    DerivedObject(DerivedOption option)
        : BaseObject(&this->option)
        , option(std::move(option))
    {}

    DerivedOption option;
};
```

It's still peculiar, because you're passing pointer to not-yet-constructed member `option` to constructor of `BaseObject`

Also you should remove implementation of copy-assignment operator in `BaseOption`/`DerivedOption` or implement copy-constructor as well.

---

In your example function `OptionConstructor` is called even before constructor of `BaseObject`, moreover that function calls copy-assignment operator of not-yet constructed member `option`, which I suppose is undefined behavior (in your case it renders to program crash).

Comment: Yes But I need the option to be instantiated before the BaseOject constructor  because I use option insite BaseOject constructor.

Comment: Then it is better to add member function `Init(BaseOption *)` to `BaseObject` class, and call that function from the body of `DerivedObject` constructor

Comment: So did you say that my string is built after the constructor call ?

Comment: Members are initialized after constructors of base classes.